# Finding Large Example Graphs

Tags: graph

I am doing a project that involves processing large, sparse graphs.  Does anyone know of any publicly available data sets that can be processed into large graphs for testing?  I'm looking for something like a Facebook friend network, or something a little smaller with the same flavor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you asked nicely, you might be able to get Brian O'Meara's data set for treetapper. It's a pretty nice example of real-world data in that genre. Particularly, you'd probably be interested in the coauthorship data.

http://www.treetapper.org/

http://www.brianomeara.info/

Answer (score 4):

I found the [Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/index.html) pretty useful.

Answer (score 2):

[Github's API](http://develop.github.com/) is nice for building out graphs. I've messed around using the python lib [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) to generate graphs of that network. Here's some [sample code](http://github.com/dcolish/github-scraper/blob/master/githubscraper/graph.py) if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for the double post, evidently I can only post two links at a time since I have <10 reputation...

DIMACS also has some data sets from their [cluser challenge](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/dimacs10/downloads.shtml) and there's always the [Graph500](http://www.graph500.org/).  The Boost Graph Library has a number of graph generators as well.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you consider "large", there's the [University of Florida Sparse Matrix Collection](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/matrices/) as well as some [DIMACS Road Networks](http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/challenge9/download.shtml) (mostly planar of course).

Answer (score 1):

A few other ones:

- [Newman's page](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/netdata/)
- [Barabasi's page](http://www3.nd.edu/~networks/resources.htm)
- [Pajek software](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/pajek/data/gphs.htm)
- [Arena's page](http://deim.urv.cat/~aarenas/data/welcome.htm)
- [Network Science](http://www.network-science.org/)